# Need help adding a new switch to 3 way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

[image]

I would like to add a single pole switch to a separate light fixture. I want to add the new switch to what would be the first switch in the picture I attached. This switch has the power source coming into the switch box. I am just not sure how to attach the first switch to the new switch.

Comment: Can you, *without disconnecting any wires*, take pictures of the existing switches/wires/etc. and add them to your question?

Comment: depending which side you want to add the new switch, left or right 3 way switch

Comment: It looks like the yellow wire in the diagram is supposed to be ground; odd choice unless they are trying to represent an uninsulated wire's copper color...  Note that the approach shown in this picture isn't the only way to wire a three-way circuit, which is why we need to know how YOUR switch boxes have been wired.

Answer (score 0):

So You're adding a single pole switch to the same location as the first switch, right?  You'll need to change out the single gane switch box to a double gang one or replace your 3-way switch with a combination 3-way, single switch. Pigtail the black always hot to the single switch. Route the load side wire of the single switch and a neutral pigtail to the location of the separate light fixture.